# how to add days in javascript specific date format

Tags: javascript, date, date-format

Hello I have date in this format `03/08/12` where 03 is month, 08 is day and 12 is year. Now I want to add days in it. I have tried following but not getting the exact result

```
  checkindate = new Date($("#checkindate").val());
  checkindate.setDate(checkindate.getDate()+no_of_nights);
  $("#checkoutdate").val((checkindate.getMonth()+1)+"/"+checkindate.getDate()+"/"+checkindate.getYear());
```

But is is giving unexpected result and I am unable to understand in which part of date it is adding. Can Any body tell me how can I do this?

Regards

Comment: potential duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/563406/add-days-to-datetime-using-java-script

Answer (score 0):

What you have now will not work in all situations because you are adding the `no_of_nights` to the Day value which means you could have 31 + 5, setDate() will not give you the expected outcome with a value of 36.

You must figure out how many months, days, years, etc. you want to add.

Javascript works off of miliseconds from 1/1/1970 and not normal time.

Comment: dude no_of_nights is a variable which means no of days. I didn't understand you answer.Can you please explain?

Comment: @user1272333, I understand what the variable is, but read the documentation on setDate() it accepts values 1-31.  So if you get the current date as March 31, and then you add the variable, say 5 days, you end up with 36 days, which javascript will not add correctly to the date object, that is why you are getting an unexpected result.  The setDate() method assumes you are just trying to set the day value of the Date object within the current month that it is set to.  it doesn't understand 36 as an input parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Your code works perfectly, but **make sure `no_of_nights` is not a string**.  That's probably your issue: the addition operation `checkindate.getDate()+no_of_nights` becomes a *concatenation* operation if `no_of_nights` is a string.

```
8 + 5 = 13
8 + "5" = "85"
```

Very different!

**Solution:** use `parseInt(no_of_nights)`.